# jQuery AddressPicker languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation

Is there a way to change language to any other than English in the [AddressPicker](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker) jQuery plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question:

Language for this plugin can be specified in the header script tag

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ru"></script>
```